# Get number of choices from entity field in Twig template

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a Symfony 2 form for a Doctrine entity with an entity choice field for a ManyToMany relationship. It is possible for the choice field to not have any choices - how can I test for this in Twig?

Example: The form is for a "Deal" entity, which can optionally be assigned to a "Location" entity. I render the "Location" entity field like this:

```
{{ form_label(edit_form.locations) }}
{{ form_errors(edit_form.locations) }}
{{ form_widget(edit_form.locations) }}
```

The field is set to render with checkboxes. However, it is possible that no "Location" records will exist. In this scenario the user will see the label "Locations: " but no check boxes. I would like to have a conditional statement that displays a message, something along the lines of this:

```
{{ form_label(edit_form.locations) }}
{{ form_errors(edit_form.locations) }}
{{ form_widget(edit_form.locations) }}
{% if edit_form.locations.choices|length == 0 %}
  You haven't created any Locations yet!
{% endif %}
```

Anybody know of a way to achieve this?

Comment: Found the answer myself, don't have a high enough reputation to answer my own question that fast: `{% if edit_form.locations.get('choices')|length == 0 %}`

Comment: newest version should use:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115245/symfony2-deprecated-get-in-formview-replacement

because in new versions this code would breake, tested on Symfony 2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to help others...
In newer versions it would be:

```
{% if edit_form.locations.vars.choices|length == 0%}
```

I was actually looking to do this, so I'll share:
If you had an embedded form and you wanted to do the same type of check except pulling the data from the prototype (in case the form is not generated with any children forms)

```
{% if form.childForms.vars.prototype.field.vars.choices|length == 0 %}
```

"childForms" being the embedded form type and "field" being the select field you want the choices out of...

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
{% if edit_form.locations.get('choices')|length == 0 %}
```