# Symfony2: deprecated get in FormView replacement?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In versions < 2.3, the attribute

```
data-prototype="{% filter escape %}{% include 'ManaClientBundle:Member:member_prototype.html.twig' with {'form': form.members.get('prototype')} %}{% endfilter %}"
```

allowed the prototype to display as a row of cells.  In 2.3, of course, this line generates the error

> Method "get" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not
>   exist

Per UPGRADE-2.1.md, *get* is deprecated.  It cannot be replaced by the suggested *vars* as it produces a similar error.  How can I (easily?) render the prototype as before in 2.3?  Using

```
data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.members.vars.prototype)|e }}"
```

does not provide a useful solution regardless of div or table settings for twig:resources:form in config.yml.

#### prototype

```
<tr id="member-form">
<td><input class="smallform" type="radio" name="household[isHead]" value="__name__"></td>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.include, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.fname, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.sname, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.dob, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.sex, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.ethnicity, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}</td>
<td><a id="removeTr" class="smallbutton" href="#" onclick="removeTr(this)">Remove</a>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace `form.members.get('prototype')` with `form.members.vars.prototype`.

Could have been a whole lot clearer what to do, but fewer than infinite monkeys found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Above won't work for me when extending block.
In 2.3.7 at least, I was able to access vars like:

{% block form_row %}
{{ form.vars.value }}
.....
{% endblock %}

And when an ArrayCollection like:

{% block sonata_type_collection_widget %}
    {% for child in form %}
        {{ child.vars.form.vars.value.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

Hope that helps someone.